# Django Navigation Text on HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, django

I'm building a Django web app, which is comunicating with a custom OpenERP module.

This module, shows a series of pages in formatted html, it is like a virtual book, with Titles, chapters, contents...

Right now, the Django web app, it's divided into three frames, data from OpenERP module is shown on mainfraime, and on topframe, I got the buttons, which should do the navigation into OpenERP data.

So far I have three buttons, 'Start', 'Next', and 'Back'.

On start button I got this code:

```
    <div class="masthead" align="right"><ul ><input type="button" value="Inicio" onclick="javascript:top.frames['centrale'].location='/get_contents/INDEX/'; return true;"></ul></div>
```

Here, `location` points to the first page on a book, or better, the 'cover' of this book. Being `INDEX`.

Now for example, in next button i got this:

```
    <div class="masthead" align="right"><ul ><input type="button" value="Siguiente" onclick="javascript:top.frames['centrale'].location='/get_contents/NE5/A0100000/'; return true;"></ul></div>
```

Points to the first page of the book, but of course, there are plenty of pages, with codes like: `A0100000, A0100101, A0100102, A0100103, A0100104` and so on...

I can't go with the actual approach, because i'm just going to launch first page on `Next` button, not the subsequent, and obvisouly can't create like 900 buttons either.

So, I think the best approach could be (correct me if I'm wrong) A Jquery code, 'storing' what the user is seeing and then go to the next page, so far I've tried some Jquery but failed to make it work, i'm not really sure if this is the best approach to achieve what i'm looking for in Django.

I hope I've explained myself, Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

PS = If you need me to post some code to understand better the situation, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use onclick. Instead, use:

```
...<input id="prevButton">...</input>...
...<input id="nextbutton">...</input>...

// In the js

<script>
    $('#prevButton').click(function(){
        // Code here
    });

    $('#nextButton').click(function(){
        // Code here
    });
</script>
```

Then, in your django view, add a JSON string containing links to all the pages in your app to the template context.

```
for page in all_pages:
    list_of_all_pages.append(page.permalink()) # Something like this

jsonlist = json.dumps(list_of_all_pages) # Add this to the template context
```

Back to html:

```
<script>

    // Roughly like this
    var listOfPages = JSON.parse('{{ jsonlist|escapejs }}');
    var currentPage = 0;

    $('#prevButton').click(function(){
        currentPage--;
        top.frames['centrale'].location=listOfPages[currentPage];
    });

    // currentPage++ on the nextButton

    ...
```

If you want, you can create a separate view to serve the json, then get it using `jQuery.getJSON` instead of injecting it to the html.

Comment: Hello, thank you! You mean in JSON string I should put links to ALL of the pages of the OpenERP module? Or just internal Django pages?

Comment: Well, the pages you meant with codes like `A0100000, A0100101, A0100102, A0100103, A0100104`.

Comment: Ooook :) Got it, gonna try it and write back, thank so much again!